# Number of incoming link fo each DBpedia resource

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I have the SPARQL DBpedia Query below:

```
PREFIX rdfs:   <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX vrank:<http://purl.org/voc/vrank#>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT distinct  ?Nom ?resource ?url (count( (?o) as ?nb))
 WHERE{
   ?resource rdfs:label ?Nom.
   ?resource foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?url.
   ?resource dbpedia-owl:wikiPageWikiLink ?o
   ?Nom <bif:contains> "Apple".
   FILTER ( langMatches( lang(?Nom), "EN" )).
MINUS {?resource dbo:wikiPageRedirects|dbo:wikiPageDisambiguates  ?dis}
    }
Group By  ?Nom ?resource ?url
```

I want to get the number of incoming links of each entitie within wikipedia. How can I proceed?
Thanks

Comment: First of all, add a comment because nobody answer within 7 hours is strange.

Comment: Secondly, it depends on whether the DBpedia endpoint that you're working on contains triples with the predicate http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageWikiLink . If so you could use SPARQL 1.1 GROUP BY + COUNT() features.

Comment: @AKSW I use http://dbpedia.org/sparql for querying. i try dbpedia-owl:wikiPageExternalLink but it doesn't work.

Comment: @AKSW sorry i mean i try  dbpedia-owl:wikiPageWikiLink  but it soesn't work.

Comment: The answer you wish for cannot really be retrieved from the [`http://dbpedia.org/sparql`](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) endpoint, because that is a periodically updated static data set, and the Wikipedia data is a constantly moving target.

Comment: You can get a reasonably accurate answer from the [`http://dbpedia-live.openlinksw.com/sparql`](http://dbpedia-live.openlinksw.com/sparql) or [`http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql`](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql) endpoints, because these hold a dynamic data set, constantly updating based on extraction from the Wikipedia changelog firehose.

Comment: Even here, however, you'll only get a count of crosslinks as found within the DBpedia data set, which is a subset of Wikipedia content.  Now, if that's what you're looking for, then I suggest you show us the queries you tried that "didn't work" so we can suggest correction.

Comment: @TallTed I am looking for computing  a weight  associated with each 1.DBpedia resource of the query above: this weight is the fraction of incoming links associated with each sense / the total number of incoming  links  for  all  senses  associated. (sense=resource).

2.I am trying the two endpoint that you gave me, and always an empty result.

Comment: Playing with your query reveals that the `dbpedia-owl:wikiPageWikiLink` clause reduces the result to zero rows, because this predicate does not actually occur in the data set.  I suggest you bring your question to the [DBpedia Discussion mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/dbpedia-discussion), as it's not programming related, and so not suited to this site.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50171855/7879193

Answer (score 1):

First of all syntax:

you are missing a dot after ?o,
also it should be bif:contains, not `<bif:contains>`.

Next:

i ran this simpler query:

```
PREFIX rdfs:   <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX vrank:<http://purl.org/voc/vrank#>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT distinct  ?Nom ?resource
 WHERE{
   ?resource rdfs:label ?Nom.
   ?Nom bif:contains "Apple".
}
```

which produced a lot of results....
now i added this triple:

```
PREFIX rdfs:   <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX vrank:<http://purl.org/voc/vrank#>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT distinct  ?Nom ?resource
 WHERE{
   ?resource rdfs:label ?Nom.
   ?resource dbpedia-owl:wikiPageWikiLink ?o.
   ?Nom bif:contains "Apple".
}
```

which returned no results.

this means there is no triple containing apple in its object literal, where the subject has a wikiPageWikiLink in the whole endpoint.

If this property does exist, its instances are not included in the official endpoint since there is no triple containing this property (I checked). This is probably due to the fact, that the official endpoint does not hold every dbpedia dataset, or it might be deprecated.