# Difference in count result of a SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I have this query:

```
PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> 
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
select  ?Nom ?resource ?url (count( distinct (?o) as ?nb))
 where {
   ?resource rdfs:label ?Nom.
   ?resource foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?url.
   ?resource rdf:type ?p.
   ?resource dbpedia-owl:wikiPageExternalLink  ?o
FILTER ( langMatches( lang(?Nom), "EN" )).
?Nom <bif:contains> "Apple".
MINUS { ?resource dbo:wikiPageRedirects|dbo:wikiPageDisambiguates ?dis   }
      }Group By  ?Nom ?resource ?url
```

Now if i replace the line

```
    select  ?Nom ?resource ?url (count( distinct (?o) as ?nb))
```

by:

```
    select  ?Nom ?resource ?url (count( (?o) as ?nb))
```

it give me  different results:
For example the first example:

```
| "Simon Apple"@en            | <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Simon_Apple>           | <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_Apple>           | 4   |
| "Golden Orange (apple)"@en  | <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Golden_Orange_(apple)> | <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Orange_(apple)> | 1   |
| "Apple Watch"@en            | <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Apple_Watch>           | <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Watch>           | 1   |
```

The second example give me:

and the result of the seconde one:

```
| "Simon Apple"@en            | <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Simon_Apple>           | <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_Apple>           | 80   |
| "Golden Orange (apple)"@en  | <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Golden_Orange_(apple)> | <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Orange_(apple)> | 14   |
| "Apple Watch"@en            | <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Apple_Watch>           | <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Watch>           | 4   |
```

what is the difference? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Because of the rdf:type triple pattern, you'll get several rows for the same resource, thus, the same ?o occurs in several rows for the same resource and without DISTINCT is counted as often as it occurs. By the way, the triple pattern with rdf:type is more or less useless in this query.

Comment: @AKSW yes exactly, it was the problem of rdf:type, despite that it was a typo. it is a former example, that i have copying without paying attention. Thanks a lot.
Now i want to add dbpedia-owl:wikiPageWikiLink , but it doesn't work. Any idea about that?

Comment: You mean, now you want to get back to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34810267/number-of-incoming-link-fo-each-dbpedia-resource ...